# How does TLS protect against a MITM cipher suite downgrade?

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle

The initial TLS handshake agrees on a cipher suite to use, but what stops an attacker from MITM-ing the initial handshake and downgrading the cipher suites?

Comment: I feel like this question is already answered somewhere on this site, but the quick summary is that even the initial request is protected by a signature... maybe I'll find the original soon...

Comment: You're interested in the `Finished` message referenced in this answer: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/20847/149676

Comment: Also see this: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71979/how-well-is-the-ssl-tls-handshake-protected-against-modifications?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the [Finished message](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.9) is a hash of the entire handshake, encrypted with the negotiated keys. The negotiated keys are derived by something protected by asymmetric cryptography. [Validation of the Finished message validates the transcript of the handshake](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#appendix-F.1.3).

This is probably answered in multiple answers on SE for "How does TLS work?".